# Oracle APEX PL/SQL Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, literals

I have got this PL/SQL statement:

```
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM REI_RETAIL_FACTOR_PARTS P
    WHERE  DEALER_NUMBER = :P13_FILTER_DEALER;

    INSERT INTO REI_RETAIL_FACTOR_PARTS
    (
        SELECT
            RF.TEILE_NR as "PART_NR",
            :P13_OVERWRITE_VALUE as "REQUESTED_RATE",
            sysdate as "REQUEST_DATE",
            :P13_FILTER_DEALER as "DEALER_NUMBER"
        FROM REI_RETAIL_FACTOR RF
        WHERE DEALER_NUMBER = :P13_FILTER_DEALER
    );
END;
```

The error is:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.

This is really frustrating, because I never try to format anything.
So, why the hell do I keep getting this error?

Comment: Sounds like an implicit `TO_DATE` being invoked.  You haven't specified the target columns for the insert, maybe you are inserting one of the non-date values (not `sysdate`) into a date column?

Comment: This might also be an implicit `TO_NUMBER`, I think.

Comment: True - a date or a number column could fail like this.

Comment: the value that's returned from the select seems causing error , can you show us the output of the select with the ddl of the table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ORA-01861:  literal does not match format string.

You have error with `INSERT` syntax. Possible solution:

a) define column list:

```
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM REI_RETAIL_FACTOR_PARTS P
    WHERE  DEALER_NUMBER = :P13_FILTER_DEALER;

    INSERT INTO REI_RETAIL_FACTOR_PARTS(column_name1, ...)
        SELECT
            RF.TEILE_NR as "PART_NR",
            :P13_OVERWRITE_VALUE as "REQUESTED_RATE",
            sysdate as "REQUEST_DATE",
            :P13_FILTER_DEALER as "DEALER_NUMBER"
        FROM REI_RETAIL_FACTOR RF
        WHERE DEALER_NUMBER = :P13_FILTER_DEALER;
END;
```

b) Remove `()` (warning! column order in select is crucial):

```
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM REI_RETAIL_FACTOR_PARTS P
    WHERE  DEALER_NUMBER = :P13_FILTER_DEALER;

    INSERT INTO REI_RETAIL_FACTOR_PARTS
        SELECT
            RF.TEILE_NR as "PART_NR",
            :P13_OVERWRITE_VALUE as "REQUESTED_RATE",
            sysdate as "REQUEST_DATE",
            :P13_FILTER_DEALER as "DEALER_NUMBER"
        FROM REI_RETAIL_FACTOR RF
        WHERE DEALER_NUMBER = :P13_FILTER_DEALER;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you! The coloumn order was incorrect, I thought that defining the correct names would be sufficient.